# Intellij 13 Community + CVS. Error while refreshing list of commited changes

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

i'm having issue with my Intellij 13 Community Edition and CVS repository. 
When in Changes tab / repository i'm trying to refresh repository status Intelij often, but not all the time, stucks on

> command 'rlog' running for :pserver:user@repo_adress

After 30-45 minutes of executing this task i'm killing it manually because it annoys me.

It also happends while background refresing cvs changes which is very important for me. I want to monitor changes without updating classes all the time.

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
I've solved it. It was fairly easy. Our cvs repository is kinna slow and likes to reject requests. Increasing timeout helped with that issue and now it works just fine :).

Path to this setting is :

> Main menu bar -> VCS -> CVS -> Global Settings -> Timeout